# Preload Images from URL React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I get a list of image url from an API, and I display them 1 by 1 in a carousel.
I do `<img src={url} />`. But with this solution my images always need to load when they appear.
Then I want to preload them in ComponentDidMount just after my API call. Maybe something like "stock" them.

Below a method I also try but it doesn't work

```
.then(result => {
  result.forEach(element => {
      const image = element.image.fileName;
      element.image = new Image();
      element.image.src = image;
  });
  console.log(result)

  this.setState({loading: false, error: null, partners: result});
})
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKlJu.png)
with the code I write before I have this result, and if write `<img src={url}` my image take some milliseconds to load. And kill the user experience.
On the first image below you can see the array. With image in image and if I click on the image I have the warning that I show on the second screenshot.

[image: console 1]
[image: console 2]

Comment: What result are you getting? Is there any network requests happening from the browser?

Comment: I edit to post for make it more clear and answer to your question @CameronDowner

Comment: Those look like bad src URLs instead if the image not being preloaded. If you check the network tab in the browser developer tools it should tell you whether the images are being loaded or not https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: yes sorry I will add an image in the edit, I already saw something goes wrong in the dev tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're missing is listening to the `onload` event. Basically you can wait until all your images are loaded. In the meantime you could show a loading spinner.

Sample code in `ComponentDidMount()`:

```js
    // Load all images
    const images = await myAPICall().map(image => new Promise((rs, rj) => {
     const img = new Image();
     img.onload = () => rs(img);
     img.onerror = () => rj();
    }))

  await Promise.all(images)
  this.setState({loading: false})
```

You could then render your carousel just by checking if the loading has finished.

PS: I'm using async/await here so makes sure you try/catch and add `async` in front of the function.